# Get the top 5 score values in JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, loops

So I am trying to get the top five values of score in this JSON Object.

http://rest.learncode.academy/api/guessinggame/scores

Right now I am getting all the values.

The objects in the array have a score property. I am trying to get the top 5 objects with the highest score values and spit them out in an ordered list.

Thank you in advance for the help!

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/guessinggame/scores',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("Scores!", data); //the new item is returned with an ID

      $.each(data, function(i, score) {
        $('.score-list').append('<li> Name: ' + score.name + '<br/>' + 'Score: ' + score.score);
      })
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you'll want to convert your JSON to an array of objects using:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(data);
```

And after that you can sort using the following sort function, which will sort from lowest to highest.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.score - b.score;
});
```

If you want to sort from highest to lowest you can swap a and b in the sort function. E.g:

```
x.sort(function(a, b) {
return b.score - a.score;
});
```

Then if you want, you can convert back to JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked wonders! Appreciate the human explanation through the code and its function.

Comment: No worries! Play around with the function, you can try sort by different variations. You could even filter out certain results using the below function:

E.g you could filter out the scores that are `!= 0` by using the filter function: `arr.filter( function (obj) {return obj.score != 0});` @GarrettSanderson

Comment: Awesome! I will definitely mess around with that!

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Array.sort() in JavaScript, it uses a compare function to sort data(but the compare function uses unicode values, that's why I used *parseInt()* )

```
    data.sort(function(a, b){
        if (parseInt(a.score) < parseInt(b.score)) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (parseInt(a.score) > parseInt(b.score)) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    })
```

Then you could use *Array.slice()* to get first n elements

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(b.score, 10) - parseInt(a.score, 10);
});
```

You can sort the data with the given score value in the array. You can use the `<ol>` tag to render an ordered list.

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/guessinggame/scores',
    success: function(data) {
      data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt(b.score, 10) - parseInt(a.score, 10);
      });
      $.each(data, function(i, score) {
        if (i < 5) { // The top 5.
          $('.score-list').append('<li> Name: ' + score.name + '<br/>' + 'Score: ' + score.score);
        }

      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="score-list"></ol>
```